# magento product page review link

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have an magento store it's version 1.6.

And I want to change the review link to a tap to call so customers from mobile to instant call me.

Can you help me do that?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: use turn on template path hints or use Easy Template Path Hints.

Comment: try this <a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>

Comment: Thanks, it's ok, but I need to know where to modify the product page template please?